# stored procedure throughing me an error whille executing in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
 create table `pivot` (
 `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
 `categoryid` int(11) default null,
 `processdate` date default null,
 `percentchange` int(11) default null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=myisam auto_increment=9 default charset=latin1;

/*Data for the table `pivot` */

insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (1,4,'2011-05-10',1);
insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (2,4,'2011-05-11',22);
insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (3,4,'2011-05-12',3);
insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (4,7,'2011-05-10',4);
insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (5,7,'2011-05-11',5);
insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (6,12,'2011-05-10',6);
insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (7,12,'2011-05-12',7);
insert  into `pivot`(`id`,`categoryid`,`processdate`,`percentchange`) values (8,4,'2011-05-13',12);



delimiter //
drop procedure if exists dynamic_view2//
create procedure dynamic_view2(in sdate date,in edate date)
begin
declare finish int default 0;
declare cdate date;
declare str varchar(10000) default "select categoryid,";
declare curs cursor for select processdate from pivot where processdate    between sdate and edate group by processdate;
declare continue handler for not found set finish = 1;
open curs;
my_loop:loop
fetch curs into cdate;
if finish = 1 then
leave my_loop;
end if;
set str = concat(str, "max(case when processdate = '",cdate,"' then     percentchange else null end) as `",cdate,"`,");
end loop;
close curs;
set str = substr(str,1,char_length(str)-1);
set @str = concat(str," from pivot
        group by categoryid");

prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

Phpmyadmin throughing an error while executing stored procedure . Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve pivot operation in mysql/phpmyadmin , i tried most of the ways but everything ended up in error .

From comment:11 errors were found during analysis. Unrecognized statement type. (near "procedure" at position 0) Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 134) Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 155) Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 213) Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 332) Unrecognized statement type. (near "open" at position 388) Unrecognized statement type. (near "if" at position 438)

Comment: Add full error text to question

Comment: Hi sorry for not being clear . below are the errors  i get   11 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized statement type. (near "procedure" at position 0)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 134)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 155)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 213)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 332)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "open" at position 388)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "if" at position 438)